# How to move characters inside brackets to another part of a string?

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, data-cleaning, stringr

I'm trying to detect characters of a string which are inside brackets and take those exact characters and replace them into a different string. These are in multiple columns, ref1:ref4.

eg. The values in the columns that are:

```
"Ref Other Spot (Long Line)"
"Ref Other Spot (Short)"
"Ref Other Spot (Terrier Join)"
```

and change these to:

```
"Ref to Long Line"
"Ref to Short"
"Ref to Terrier Join"
```

I'm using mutate(across()) in this way to try and replace them:

```
mutate(across(ref1:ref4,
~ str_replace_all(.x, "Ref Other Spot ([.])", paste0("Ref to [.]"))))
```

But this isn't picking up the "Long Line", "Short" etc. I think my regular expression is missing something (pattern [.])
I'm also not sure if it will be able to both detect then paste the same word back into the expression.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
str_replace_all(.x, "(Ref)\\s+Other\\s+Spot\\s*\\(([^()]*)\\)", "\\1 to \\2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T0ouW4/1).

*Details*:

- `(Ref)` - `Ref` string captured into Group 1 (`\1`)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `Other\s+Spot` - `Other Spot` with any one or more whitespaces between the two words
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2 (`\2`): zero or more chars other than parentheses
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (but less straightforward than Wiktor's):

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c(ref1:ref4),
                # If there's an expression in parentheses ...
                ~ ifelse(str_detect(., "\\([^(]+\\)"),
                        #... extract it and attach it to "Ref to":
                         str_c("Ref to ", str_extract(., "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))")), .)))
```